How to get access and refresh token for integrating two applications using Google AppScript
I am integrating Zoho CRM with Google Drive, I am able to connect my Zoho application with google drive. Now I want to extract access_token and refresh_token from the google drive authorization url which consist of authorization code. I can manully extract the tokens, but I want to build an integration between both applications for different user so different user will have different authorization code right? So I want to get tokens in generic for every user so I need to code for it but I am unable to get tokens via my Google Apps Script code or zoho crm custom function i.e. Deluge programming.
I want tokens to integrate my Zoho account and Google account so that I will be able to manipulate data from both applications and updation will be shown in both ends.
I have connected my Zoho account with Google Drive but I do not able to establish connection between both applications.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

How the integration is being done needs to be clarified.
